# simple Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

Sorry for this simple question, but i'm missing the forest through the trees.

These are my tables (i left the sparepart-table because i'm only looking for two special fk's):
[image]
<sub>(source: [bilder-hochladen.net](http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/4709-kx.jpg))</sub>

I need the distinct rows from tabData which are referenced in the child-table tabDataDetail with fiSparePart=8837 **and** 8969.
The following gives me only that rows which have at least one sparepart, but i need those which have both. They are also not distinct, because of the having clause.

```
SELECT     tabData.idData
FROM         tabData INNER JOIN
                      tabDataDetail ON tabData.idData = tabDataDetail.fiData
GROUP BY tabData.idData, tabDataDetail.fiSparePart
HAVING   tabDataDetail.fiSparePart IN (8837, 8969)
ORDER BY tabData.idData
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the tabData records that have both 8837 and 8969 as spare parts. You can use DISTINCT, and you don't need the group by.

```
SELECT  
 DISTINCT tabData.idData
 FROM    tabData 
 WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM tabDataDetail
                 WHERE tabData.idData = tabDataDetail.fiData
                   AND tabDataDetail.fiSparePart = 8837)
   AND   EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM tabDataDetail
                 WHERE tabData.idData = tabDataDetail.fiData
                   AND tabDataDetail.fiSparePart = 8969)
 ORDER BY tabData.idData
```

Comment: Thanks. When changing "FROM tabDataDetail.fiSparePart" to "FROM tabDataDetail" it works :)

Comment: @Tim - Ooops, sorry for that :). Fixed now.

Comment: Btw, the DISTINCT keyword is not necessary because idData is the PK of tabData and therefore is unique ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT     tabData.idData
FROM         tabData INNER JOIN
                      tabDataDetail ON tabData.idData = tabDataDetail.fiData
WHERE tabDataDetail.fiSparePart IN (8837, 8969)
GROUP BY tabData.idData, tabDataDetail.fiSparePart
HAVING COUNT(distinct tabDataDetail.fiSparePart  ) > 1
ORDER BY tabData.idData
```

Here is an example

```
create table #bla (idData int, fiSparePart int)
insert #bla values(1,8837)
insert #bla values(1,8969)
insert #bla values(2,8837)
insert #bla values(2,8837)
insert #bla values(2,8837)



SELECT     idData
FROM        #bla
WHERE   fiSparePart IN (8837, 8969)
GROUP BY idData
HAVING COUNT(distinct fiSparePart) > 1
```

Comment: What if 8837 occurs twice, but 8969 doesn't occur at all?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two tables for this, if all you're getting from tabData is the primary key (which also exists in tabDataDetail as the foreign key).  This is assuming tabData is a parent table to tabDataDetail.

```
SELECT a.fiData
FROM (SELECT fiData FROM tabDataDetail WHERE fiSparePart = 8837) a
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT fiData FROM tabDataDetail WHERE fiSparePart = 8969) b
   ON a.fiData = b.fiData
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint, when changed "SELECT fiData" to "SELECT a.fiData" it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT     tabData.idData
 FROM         tabData INNER JOIN
                  tabDataDetail ON tabData.idData = tabDataDetail.fiData
 WHERE   tabDataDetail.fiSparePart IN (8837, 8969)
 GROUP BY tabData.idData, tabDataDetail.fiSparePart
 ORDER BY tabData.idData
```

Comment: ...and also the query does not return all tabData-records that have both spareparts.